# How to make changes in wordpress template. Css direct edit not working

Tags: css, wordpress, redux-framework

I want to make small changes in wordpress template css, but despite I change desired values (for instance font-height), changes are not applied on actual page(I've tried multiple browsers, cleaned browser and wordpress cache...).
I've noticed that this theme is using Redux framework, so it seems that this "cause" this problem with all these changes.
I would not mind to delete this (or any other) framework and make all my custom changes directly with css, but I'm not sure how to do it properly.
I have knowledge of html & css, but not wordpress system.

Comment: I've tried to edit it via admin panel, and also I've tried to edit original css, but without any success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this plugin :

[Simple Custom Css](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/)

Comment: Not entirely what I wanted, as I would prefer to edit css in real editor, BUT it works and does it's job anyway, so thank you!!! :)

Comment: [Custom CSS Injector](https://wordpress.org/plugins/css-injector/) works 2 times faster than Simple Custom CSS plugin.